# Which control volume is being used?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Consider the control volume shown in [this question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/169AHk555gV8JtwZtXmwiiI5bPtBYAXik/view?usp=drivesdk)

To evaluate the lift, the integral form of the conservation of momentum was applied as shown in [this solution video](https://youtu.be/LzL4GjeJwoI)
(Skip to 2:07 for evaluation part)

Here, the surface of the airfoil AND the surface of the rectangle is being considered for the control surface integral. So what exactly is the control volume? I can't think of a control volume whose control surface is the airfoil and the rectangle boundary.

This question is from a edx course which is not active anymore so I can't ask the doubts there

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear from the video what the control volume is.  It is all the air inside the rectangle and outside the airfoil.  Everything he said in the video makes perfect sense in this context.

The problem is done pretty much the same way the overall momentum balance is used when we analyze the force exerted on a pipe wall by fluid flowing in a curved pipe.

Comment: Thanks. That clears it